# memory addresses in Hex View are always byte-aligned in new versions of IDA

Tags: ida

In IDA < 7, Hex View shows addresses starting from any memory location you choose (both synchronize or G + address). For example, asking for 0019E7EC shows:

```
0019E7EC  48 4B 46 42 39 39 2D 32  51 4D 38 35 33 2D 43 41  HKFB99-2QM853-CA
0019E7FC  32 30 30 30 00 CD 48 01  A0 E8 19 00 41 CD E1 5D  2000.-H.áÞ..A-ß]
```

In IDA > 7, Hex View shows addresses only aligned on 16-byte boundaries (address & 0FFFFFFF0). For example, asking for 0019E7EC now shows:

```
0019E7E0  A4 EA 19 00 5C 17 EF 00  00 F0 2C 00 48 4B 46 42  ¤ê..\.ï..ð,.HKFB
0019E7F0  39 39 2D 32 51 4D 38 35  33 2D 43 41 32 30 30 30  99-2QM853-CA2000
```

Is there a way to restore the old Hex View behavior?